# python: function sub of re module

Tags: python, regex, string

This should be a vary basic thing to do, but I can't get it to work despite following a lot of examples from the web. 
What I'm trying is to use the sub function to get the name of a file from a complete path.

So, if

```
output="/home/alvarofeal/Desktop/prueba_sub.avi"
re.sub(r'(.*\/)*', "", output)
print output

output: /home/alvarofeal/Desktop/prueba_sub.avi
```

Shouldn't the output be:

```
prueba_sub.avi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub()` returns a *new string*. Strings are immutable and cannot be changed in-place.

You are ignoring the return value; store it back in `output` if you want to replace the old value:

```
output = "/home/alvarofeal/Desktop/prueba_sub.avi"
output = re.sub(r'(.*\/)*', "", output)
print output
```

If all you are doing is splitting the basename of a file path, you probably want to use the [`os.path.basename()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) instead though.

Comment: Rookie mistake, that worked to perfection, validating the answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do,

```
output = re.sub(r'(.*\/)*', "", output)
```

since `re.sub()` returns new string

**OR** using `ntpath`

```
>>>import ntpath
>>>ntpath.basename(output)
'prueba_sub.avi'
```

Comment: why are you using ntpath?

Comment: i think it is platform independent(forward slash and backward slash also)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this task.As a more pythonic way you can use `os.path.basename` with `str.split`:

```
>>> os.path.basename('/home/alvarofeal/Desktop/prueba_sub.avi').split('.')[0]
'prueba_sub'
```

or just use `basename` to get the name with format :

```
>>> os.path.basename('/home/alvarofeal/Desktop/prueba_sub.avi')
'prueba_sub.avi'
```

Comment: I needed to use regex because it's for school purposes, but your answer was helpful in case I sometime need to do it for my own program. Thanks